# Implicit dependency between BeanNameAutoProxyCreator and imported configuration

Tags: spring, spring-aop

At my company, we're working on an aspect-oriented trace interceptor, similar to `DebugInterceptor`.  We're configuring a `CustomizableTraceInterceptor` and using a `BeanNameAutoProxyCreator` to auto-proxy beans for AOP.

The problem we're facing is that, when we introduce the `BeanNameAutoProxyCreator` in the configuration:

```
@Configuration
@Import(BConfig.class)
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AConfig {
    @Bean
    public static BeanNameAutoProxyCreator beanNameAutoProxyCreator() {
        BeanNameAutoProxyCreator beanNameAutoProxyCreator = new BeanNameAutoProxyCreator();
        beanNameAutoProxyCreator.setInterceptorNames(new String[] {DEBUG_INTERCEPTOR_NAME});
        beanNameAutoProxyCreator.setBeanNames(new String[] {BEANS_NAMES_EXPRESSION});
        return beanNameAutoProxyCreator;
    }
}
```

We get a org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [X], where X is a Resteasy Proxy. This Resteasy Proxy is declared in `BConfig`.

Now, if I move the Resteasy Proxy bean configuration up to AConfig, this issue is solved, and `@DependsOn` solves the issue too.

My questions are 3: when is Spring able to resolve dependencies between beans? Why using a BeanNameAutoProxyCreator changes this behavior? What is the recommended way of solving this issue (BeanPostProcessor, @DependsOn, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The static `BeanNameAutoProxyCreator` depends on a normal bean (probably due to the BEANS_NAMES_EXPRESSION). Because it is static it is loaded/bootstrapped before any other beans and especially before the bean processing `@Import`. So basically when analyzing which beans to process, `BConfig` hasn't yet been loaded. That is why it works when you move the bean to `AConfig` or at a  depends-on for this bean.

I would probably revert the use of a BeanNameAutoProxyCreator and rely on the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` together with an aspect using the [bean pointcut](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/09/24/the-new-bean-pointcut/) to attach the desired interceptor.

There is also another risk in introducing the `BeanNameAutoProxyCreator` next to `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` it can lead to a proxy of a proxy being created, due to 2 different AOP strategies/mechanisms.